# Select Case / Radio Buttons / Procedures

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB and need help with my current school assignment. The gist of the assignment is to use **procedures** and **select case** to make a program that will prompt a user to answer True or False for 7 phrases and display their results. I'm having a problem of having the number right *numRight* display correctly. When I run it, numRight only goes up to a max of 2.

e.g. User hits true, true, false, true, false, true

*numRight* = 2 when in fact these are all the right answers.

Can anyone explain what is wrong in the code below? Thanks!

```
Public Class CIS14Lab4
'Publicly shared variables
Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim numRight As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnMain_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMain.Click
    counter += 1

    DisplayPhrase(counter) 'Used for displaying the phrase and adding to the numRight variable
    DisplayResult(numRight) 'Used for displaying the result to the user

    grpBoxTorF.Enabled = True
    radTrue.Checked = False
    radFalse.Checked = False

    lblDebugRight.Text = numRight 'Debugging purposes; displays numRight
End Sub

Sub DisplayPhrase(c As Integer)
    Select Case c 'Passed from counter
        Case 1 'True
            txtResult.Text = "1. The squeaky wheel gets the grease."
            TrueRight()
        Case 2 'True
            txtResult.Text = "2. Cry and you cry alone."
            TrueRight()
        Case 3 'False
            txtResult.Text = "3. Opposites attract."
            FalseRight()
        Case 4 'False
            txtResult.Text = "4. Spare the rod and spoil the child."
            FalseRight()
        Case 5 'True
            txtResult.Text = "5. Actions speak louder than words."
            TrueRight()
        Case 6 'False
            txtResult.Text = "6. Familiarity breeds contempt."
            FalseRight()
        Case 7 'True
            btnMain.Text = "Results:"
            txtResult.Text = "7. Marry in haste, repent at leisure."
            TrueRight()
    End Select
End Sub

Sub DisplayResult(r As Integer)
    If counter = 8 Then
        Select Case r 'Passed from numRight
            Case 7
                txtResult.Text = "Perfect 7/7!"
            Case 5 To 6
                txtResult.Text = "Excellent!"
            Case Is < 5
                txtResult.Text = "You might want to consider taking " &
                                 "Psychology 101."
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub TrueRight() 'Sub proc for "True" answers that are correct.
    If radTrue.Checked Then
        numRight += 1
    End If
End Sub

Sub FalseRight() 'SUb proc for "False" answers that are correct
    If radFalse.Checked Then
        numRight += 1
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You are checking the wrong result by incrementing your counter variable *before* the user answers.

Comment: @LarsTech that actually solved my problem! Wow I can't believe I over looked that. Thanks!!

Comment: TrueRight and FalseRight both do the same thing - shouldn't one decrement?

Comment: @user3697824 - can you explain? Do you mean have "false" as -1? I have two separate procedures since false is also considered a right answer.

I also have to sum up the numRight's so I can display to a user if they did perfectly, excellently or need to study up.

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I thought it was counting a net result,

Comment: No problem! I just tried to outline my issue in the post and not really the whole point of the program. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! @LarsTech figured out my problem. It was a simple oversight for me. Simply moving "counter += 1" *after* the procedures allowed it to count correctly + add up the number right. Thanks again!